# python pyparsing string: A,b,b,b,A,b,b,b*

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyparsing

I have a crazy problem.

I am trying to use pyparsing to parse something like this: (dots are unimportant suppressed text)

```
...... A
B .......
B .......
...... A
B .......
B .......
```

What I need is something like this: (to connect A and B element into one list)

```
 [ [ [A],[B,B] ], [ [A],[B,B] ] , ...]
```

This is my code which does not work and only returns the first [A]

```
table = pyparsing.OneOrMore(pyparsing.Group(A + (pyparsing.OneOrMore(pyparsing.Group(B) | pyparsing.SkipTo(B).suppress()))) | pyparsing.SkipTo(A).suppress())
```

I have already solved this pyparsing into a list like this:

```
[ [A],[B],[B], [A],[B],[B] , ...]
```

But this was not acceptable, since the A and B elements were not directly connected in one list.

Worth mentioning is that

```
table1 = pyparsing.ZeroOrMore(pyparsing.Group(A) | pyparsing.SkipTo(A).suppress())
table2 = pyparsing.ZeroOrMore(pyparsing.Group(B) | pyparsing.SkipTo(B).suppress())
```

works and return a list of all A elements and B elements.

Comment: By what criteria are you grouping the text?

Comment: @Deestan, I am sure parsing actually works, I can get a list of all A-element and B-element

Comment: I do not understand your reply, and the question in general is *very* underspecified.  Please go into detail on both the grouping, and on which bits you feel constrained to do in `pyparsing`.

Comment: @Deestan, I think the question is simple. Is it possible to pyparsing.OneOrMore(A + pyparsing.OneOrMore(B))?     What I am asking if it is possible to create a pattern with more than one OneOrMore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have OneOrMore's embedded within other OneOrMore's - it would severely limit the parsers you could write if you couldn't.

I think you might be able to adapt your existing solution if you do better grouping.  See how the Groups are defined in this toy example:

```
test = """
...... A 
B ....... 
B ....... 
...... A 
B ....... 
B ......."""

from pyparsing import Literal, Word, printables, Group, OneOrMore

A = Literal("A")
B = Literal("B")

notAorB = Word(printables, excludeChars="AB")

parser = OneOrMore(Group(A + Group(OneOrMore(B))))
parser.ignore(notAorB)

print parser.parseString(test).asList()
```

Prints:

```
[['A', ['B', 'B']], ['A', ['B', 'B']]]
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you have two options:

- rethink the way you're parsing the text
- stay happy with what you have and just clean things afterwards:
  You have a list like `your_list=[A,B,B,A,B,B]` ? You can just do

  ```
  [ [x[i], x[i+1] + x[i+2]] for i in range(len(your_list)//3)]
  ```

  the `+` will concatenate your two `[B]` lists (represented as `x[i+1]` and `x[i+2]`).

Comment: thanks, as I mentioned this was not accepted. I need to pyparse it directly into a list where A and B belong together.